# When does /tjʊ/ (Ex: Nice to meet you /miːt jʊ/) turn to /tʃʊ/ & /ʔjʊ/?

Tags: pronunciation

In this [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English), it said `/tj/` could be pronounced as `/tʃ/`

So, Nice to meet you `/... miːt jʊ/` will be `/... miːtʃʊ/`

But sometimes, I heard it as `/... miːʔjʊ/`

Watch this short [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSwypHirUkM), Freddie & Bob seem to stick with `/... miːʔjʊ/` (`ʔ` stands for glottal stop) & somehow they got a very powerful `/iː/`.

However, Lisa & Sally seem to stick with `/... miːtʃʊ/` & somehow their `/iː/` is softer and is not as powerful as Freddie & Bob's.

So, **When does `/tjʊ/` (Ex: Nice to meet you `/... miːt jʊ/`) turn to `/tʃʊ/` & `/ʔjʊ/`?**

Comment: when syllabified as mee.tyou, you get variant with the affricate. when syllabified as meet.you, you get the variant with the glide.

Comment: I don't know when to choose which but the phenomenon is (a) pretty universal  (option) among languages: [yod-coalescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-coalescence) (note those examples are for RP not AmE). It explains inter-word pairs 'Did you' -> 'Didja'. But you say 'Bless you', never 'bleshyou'

Answer (score 2):

Both are acceptable in conversation and give some indication of where the speaker transitioned through puberty, aka developed their accent. The glottal stop is common in the western US while the soft "i" with the " ch" transition between words is common in the eastern US, Australia and English speaking South Africa in my experience.

Comment: I don't think "neither is technically correct" is a useful answer, especially since both are in fact common and part of standard dialects.